# Jquery SlideToggle, prevent toggle in particular circumstance

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, slidetoggle

So I have an H3 that has a grey background rectangle. When you click anywhere in that grey background, a particular div performs a slideToggle(). This works fine.

Now, Inside that H3 I also have a  link that calls a jquery function that does something. That works fine too.

But my issue is this, since the link is inside the H3, after its functions executes, it also executes the slideToggle() because I clicked somewhere inside the H3.

So the question becomes, How do I prevent the slideToggle() from happening when I click on the link. I imagine I can use a flag but I'm hoping there is a more elegant way.

Any help would be appreciated.

**The HTML code**

```
<h3 id="data_id"> 
    <a href="#" id="random_id" >Random</a>   
</h3>

<div id="data_div_id">
    // The data here is irrelevant to the issue at hand
</div>
```

**The Jquery Code**

```
$('#data_id').click(function() {   
    $('#data_div_id').slideToggle('slow');      
}); 

$('#random_id').click(function(event) {
    // it does something irrelevant to the issue at hand
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try skipping the element you don't want the event for:

```
$('#data_id').click(function(event) {   
    if (event.target !== this)
        return;
    $('#data_div_id').slideToggle('slow');      
});
```

Like this only #data_id will trigger the toggle and since your h3's are in that div it gets executed when you click on them too, but only once from actually clicking the container

Comment: So in this example, it means that if the event did not originate from the #data_id click, then skip? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Both this answer and user125697's work great. I'll take this one because I actually will need 3 more links inside the H3. Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)** to stop the event from bubbling.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/GEkr5/)

```
$('#data_id').click(function() {   
    $('#data_div_id').slideToggle('slow');      
}); 

$('#random_id').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: This solution works great too. If you have random id's for the h3's or might have multiple at one point, my solution below might be more suitable.

Comment: @Yeronimo Or you could just simply give them all the same class instead and it'll work for multiple ones fine

Comment: Yep true. Thing is that I didn't know if they would have the same class or not. Checking if the element that got clicked is the actual element that the click is bound too tackles all that. More roads lead to Rome :)